# How to calculate how the distribution near normal

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I am applying some variable transformaion using different methods such as using log or power.
However. I am trying to calculate how is the new distribution is near to a normal distribution without looking to a histogram to compare the methods and find the best and use it

Comment: If it were me I would try and start by comparing median and mean of the new data set. For a normal distribution, they should be exactly the same, so comparing the degree of skew is one way of telling how far away from a normal distribution you are. Maybe there's some way you could loop standard deviation into it too - calculate the expected standard deviation of a normal distribution and then compare the standard deviation of your new dataset to that?

Comment: I would use `scipy.stats.normaltest` and compare the p-values